# Adding year clause to count per patients appointments

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In the following query, we count how many times the patient did not show for an appointment in the past. Now, we only want the counts for the current year. I am not succeeding in getting this part. I have put in `WHERE area WHERE year(vwgenpatapptinfo) = 2016` but it's not accepted.

```
 SELECT Distinct vwGenPatApptInfo.Appt_DateTime, vwGenPatInfo.Patient_Name, vwGenPatApptInfo.Appt_Status, vwGenPatApptInfo.Appt_Sched_Department_ID, vwGenPatApptInfo.Appt_Sched_Department_Descr, vwGenPatApptInfo.Patient_id,  vwGenPatApptInfo.Patient_number,                                                vwGenPatApptInfo.Appt_NoShow_Date,
     ISNULL(P.NotShowCount,0) AS NotShowCount
     FROM   vwGenPatInfo vwGenPatInfo INNER JOIN vwGenPatApptInfo vwGenPatApptInfo ON vwGenPatInfo.Patient_ID=vwGenPatApptInfo.Patient_ID
     LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT     Patient_ID, COUNT(Appt_Status) AS NotShowCount
                           FROM          (SELECT     Appt_DateTime, Appt_Status, Appt_Sched_Department_ID, Appt_Sched_Department_Descr, Appt_NoShow_Date, Patient_ID
                                                   FROM          vwGenPatapptInfo AS vwGenPatApptInfo
                                                   WHERE      (Appt_Status = 'N') AND (Appt_DateTime < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), - 1))) AS L 
                           GROUP BY Patient_ID) AS P ON  vwGenPatInfo.Patient_ID=P.Patient_ID
     WHERE  vwGenPatApptInfo.Appt_Status='N'
     ORDER BY vwGenPatApptInfo.Appt_Sched_Department_ID, vwGenPatApptInfo.Appt_DateTime
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the version of SQL Server you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) I think it needs to go into the *inner* WHERE - where it says  `WHERE      (Appt_Status = 'N') AND (Appt_DateTime < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), - 1))) AS L`, inside the parenthesis; and
B) it should be `year(vwgenpatapptinfo.appt_datetime) = 2016`, not only `year(vwgenpatapptinfo) = 2016`.